# How to get the status code of the http request?

Tags: python, http, request, http-status-code-404

I want to check whether I am successfully login by getting the status code. So, when I input the wrong account info and post the request, the status code of "Verifylogin.jsp" will return a error 302 (check by F12). What can I do with the `response` to achieve that? My code work for login the website, but I just dont know how to get the response header. Thank you so much for your reply.

```
def check_login(username, password):
    url = 'http://example.com/login/VerifyLogin.jsp'
    payload = {'loginid': username,
               'userpassword': password,}
    r = requests.Session()
    response = r.post(url, data= payload)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
response.status_code
```

is what you need.

Here is the manual:
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes